# How can I add a lines of code measure to a project in SonarQube from an external source?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, lines-of-code

We currently don't have access to the PL/SQL code of each project, but I get a report of the lines of code in the database schemas. I want to add this external measure to my Sonar projects so that I can report from one single source in the end.

I tried to introduce language and sensor classes for it, but that defeats the purpose of these classes, as I don't have the PL/SQL code at hand, as mentioned, just a file with the loc number per project.

I want to add the measure in a way that I see it in other plugins, such as:

```
context.saveMeasure(inputFile, CoreMetrics.LINES, lines);
context.saveMeasure(inputFile, CoreMetrics.NCLOC, ncLoc);
```

but I don't have an inputFile, I just have the loc report and the "PL/SQL" language definition class.

I think I should use one of the following methods on the context:

```
saveMeasure(Measure measure);
```

or 
    saveMeasure(Metric metric, Double value);

but how do I construct a Measure or a Metric that defines a top level value for lines of code of that language? Can anybody point me into the correct direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarQube is about source code analysis. This is not a generic reporting tool. If you don't have source code, then SonarQube is probably not the right tool for you.

Comment: I don't have access to our PL/SQL code. Our database team provides me the loc numbers via their app info data mart. Hence although this is not optimal, I wanted to add that top level figure to my already existing code analysis projects in Sonar.

This is comparable to the way the reports from Cobertura, FindBugs, etc. are added to Sonar. 

Henc back to my question: Is it possible to add a top level project measurement for loc information for a "non-analyzed" language? And if yes, how? If it is an Sonar internal mechanism, so be it, I will have to find another solution.

Comment: NCLOC is a file level measure. If you don't have an inputFile, you can't save it. Now if you are talking about NCLOC distribution by language, then this measure is computed by the platform, based on NCLOC per file, and supported language. So you can't alter it from a plugin.

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thanks a lot, Julien. I will find another solution then, and I stop fighting against Sonar concepts ;-)